# Firebase get data from Firestore v9 react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get order details from firestore using following function.
But here it does not send any response back and shows that docSnap.data() is not a function

My data base structure is - User/userid/orders/data

How can i get data as response without any error?

Here is my code below -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { collection, doc, getDoc, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";
import "./Orders.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";

const Orders = () => {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    console.log(user?.uid);
    try {
      const docRef = doc(db, `${user?.uid}/orders/`);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      console.log(docSnap);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="orders">
      <h1>orders here</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Orders;
```

Here is the entire path to the document which i expect funtion to read.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the document (in the Firebase console, showing the entire path to the document too) that you expect this code to read?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added it now

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a single order? If yes then the docRef should be `doc(db, \`users/${user?.uid}/orders/${orderId}\`);` Also the getDoc is imported from Firestore SDK right? Can you share the complete file including the imports and Firebase version .

Comment: i am trying to get every single order @Dharmaraj, i used try-catch to get the error and it shows that .data() is not a function, but in Firestore docs that function is clearly mentioned for reading from database

Comment: In that case, you should be using `getDocs()` can you share the complete file? Also what is your Firebase version?

Comment: i've added complete file, and i am using firebase version 9.6.7 @Dharmaraj

Comment: Can you include the imports as well just to check them once? Also please copy the code as text instead of image so it's easy for anyone to copy.

Comment: I've added the code @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `db` is a `FirebaseFirestore` object, this makes no sense:

```
const docRef = doc(db, `${user?.uid}/orders/`);
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
```

You're creating a reference to a document named `orders` in a collection `user?.uid`. This does not match your data structure, which would be:

```
const ordersRef = collection(db, `users/${user?.uid}/orders`);
```

So now `ordersRef` is a collection to the orders subcollection for the specific user. You can then read if by calling `getDocs`:

```
const ordersQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(ordersRef);
```

And loop through them with:

```
ordersQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
})
```